# Android Saving image from Webview and javascript enabled

Tags: android, webview

How do I save an image from webview while using setJavaScriptenabled(true) from google images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will have to capture image URL from the `<img src=""/>` element in your JavaScript and pass this value back to your code. After that you would execute a separate (Java) call to capture a stream and then save it to SD (or disk, or memory)